# Fragment in ViewPager shows isVisible as true when it's not

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to override the back button when my activity is displaying a fragment that contains a ViewPager. Basically, if the back button is selected when the viewPager fragment on the screen, I want to call this function in the viewPager fragment:

```
fun onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.currentItem > 0) {
        previousPage()
    } else {
        activity?.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Currently, in my activity I override `onBackPressed`:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val fragments = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    for (fragment in fragments) {
        if (fragment.isVisible && fragment is IRegistrationBackPressed) {
            fragment.registrationBackPressed()
            return
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

The first page of my viewPager **does not** implement IRegistrationBackPressed, therefore if you are on the first page, it should just call `super.onBackPressed`. Any other page in the viewPager implements IRegistrationBackPressed which just calls the viewPager fragment's `onBackPressed` function I showed above.

I had to do it this way because for whatever reason, the viewPager fragment does't appear in the activities fragments.... My issue however is that when I am on the first page, the 2nd page is not only in the fragment stack, but it's `isVisible` boolean is true.

To me this makes zero sense... If a fragment is not in view, why is it's visibility boolean showing true??

Comment: it's not gonna solve your issue, but depending on your viewPager off screen page limit, the other fragments isVisible are gonna be true for them. I had to override setMenuVisibility in the fragments to get a reliable boolean on the fragment visibility.

Comment: Well, it's like that to improve the performance of the viewPager. 
The fragments are loaded before they are seen by the user.
If performance is not an issue, you can try your code by setting the off screen page limit of your viewPager to 0.

Comment: Nah, thanks for the help. I'll just have to go another direction. I'm not going to sacrifice the little performance view pager already has in favor of a small feature. It's dumb that they use  `visibility` as their boolean for being loaded. Being loaded is not the same as being visible.